# Facebook forced logout breaks access tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-messenger-bot

There must be some issue with my account, because, curiously, I get logged out regularly and get asked to change my password and to validate my personality.

The problem is that on being logged out my app tokens are revoked and I have to re-generate them after I fixed my account.

I have about 10 active apps now, so it's a nightmare.
It's very inconvenient to have bot access tokens depend on user account and I'm frustrated to say I haven't found any another option yet except for re-generating them every time.

Just in case, the error says `Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user changed their password or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.`

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using a “real” account (under your proper name), and is this the only account you are using? Not really possible for us to tell why you might get logged out/asked to change your password on a regular basis - so I can only suggest that you make your account as safe as possible, i.e. using two-factor auth if possible, and what else Facebook has to offer in those regards (please consult their help section for details.)

Comment: Absolutely. I wasn't involved in any suspicious activity (as far as I can see). I just secured my account with two-factor auth